# Git and Powershell with admin rights

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I'm using Git on Windows 10 with PowerShell and everything works fine on normal instance, but recently I needed to tun powershell as Administator and I've stumbled on a weird thing - I can't clone/push/pull my remote repo - there is a Permission denied (publickey, password) error - note that my key don't have a password. Wasn't expecting this, but maybe my admin account can't acces the user ssh key and that is causing this problem. So my question is - how to I tell powershell running on admin rights to use the same ssh key as my normal user so I can work with git without problems?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Every user has their own ssh key. Administrator has a different one than your other user and the former is not allowed in your remote.

Comment: The point of an ssh key pair, among other things, is to prove your identity. You really don't want to start messing with swapping around users' identities. Instead, repeat the steps that made it possible for the other user to access the remote for Administrator, that is, add Administrator's public key to your user on GitHub / BitBucket / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on your answers I just generated a new key for administrator, and it works like it should.